# In JS for loop how substitute letter, 'a' in string 'begin_a_end' w/ array element, e.g., 'begin_vowe[i]_end'?

Tags: javascript

In a javascript for loop, I need to substitute the underscore bounded **a** with **Vowels[i]** and the quote bounded **ā** with **MacronVowels[i]** in:

```
flosType_a_withMacron()
putMacronedLetter("ā")
```

I am trying to condense a series of five functions with vowels a,b,c,d,e and ā,ē,ī,ō,ū by creating 2 arrays (see code) and replacing (in the for loop) the function with aforesaid array elements. Obviously this will only save me a few lines of code but I relatively new to coding and just want to know how to do this for learning purposes.

Here are the five functions as they current exist and work correctly.  What I want to do in wrap them into one in a for loop:

EXISTING CODE:

```
        function type_a_withMacron() {
                    putMacronedLetter("ā");
                    moveCursorToEnd(element);
        }               
        function type_e_withMacron() {
                    putMacronedLetter("ē");
                    moveCursorToEnd(element);
        }                                   
        function type_i_withMacron() {
                    putMacronedLetter("ī");
                    moveCursorToEnd(element);
        }
        function type_o_withMacron() {
                    putMacronedLetter("ō");
                    moveCursorToEnd(element);
        }
        function type_u_withMacron() {
                    putMacronedLetter("ū");
                    moveCursorToEnd(element);
        }
```

PROPOSED CODE: (what is proper formatting here, this is obv wrong, just asking)

```
const flos_Vowels = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
const flos_MacronVowels = ["ā","ē","ī","ō","ū"];
       
for(let i = 0;i < 5;i++ )
{
    function flosType_flos_[Vowels[i]]_withMacron()
    {
        putMacronedLetter("[flos_MacronVowels[i]]");
        moveCursorToEnd(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Why don't just declare a single function which takes a parameter (vowel) and works with that instead of having 5 different functions that do the same?

Comment: This is not homework. I created a Latin Noun Declension input fields where user enters value and border that turns green if correct, red if not correct.  It all works, I just want to condense the series of functions for macron buttons into fewer lines of code using for loop and try as I might have not been able to find example of what I described.